# R - Extract overdispersion parameter from glmmadmb output

Tags: r, parameters

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to extract the estimate for the dispersion parameter from the output of glmmadmb in R. I'm using a negative binomial model, and would like to use this code for several different species without having to go in and manually extract this value for the remainder of the code.

This is an example of my output:

```
  > summary(mod1)

       Call:
           glmmadmb(formula = species ~ (1 | year) + (1 | site), data = cs, 
           family = "nbinom2", link = "log")

        AIC: 8131.7 

       Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
        (Intercept)     4.05       0.19    21.3   <2e-16 ***
          ---
         Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

       Number of observations: total=798, year=53, site=15 
       Random effect variance(s):
       Group=year
                  Variance StdDev
       (Intercept)   0.1925 0.4388
       Group=site
                  Variance StdDev
       (Intercept)   0.4748  0.689

       Negative binomial dispersion parameter: 1.7211 (std. err.: 0.088936)

       Log-likelihood: -4061.86
```

I haven't found a function that extracts this value.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look at the code for the associated `print.summary` function ... or provide code that creates this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page for `glmmadmb`, says, among other things:

> Value:
>
> ```
>  An object of class ‘"glmmadmb"’ representing the model fit,
>  including (among others) components:
>
>    b: vector of fixed effects
>
>    S: covariance matrix of random effects
> ```
>
> alpha: scale/overdispersion parameter (negative binomial, Gamma,
>             beta)

So I think `mod1$alpha` (or `mod1[["alpha"]]` if you want to be very careful) should get what you want.

If the documentation weren't there, you could (1) look at the code of `glmmADMB:::print.summary.glmmadmb` as suggested by @DWin ; (2) look at `names(mod1)`, or `str(mod1)`, to find the piece of the model object that corresponded to the piece you wanted.

There probably should be an accessor method, but I don't know that there's a consistent convention in R for extracting dispersion-type parameters for models ...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. This information is very helpful. I will look into the code as well as you suggest.